# clean correctly a QVector

Tags: c++, qt, qvector

I have a `QVector`

```
QVector<const ClassA*> list;
```

and I want to know how it is what the best way to clean an `QVector`  in this case.

`ClassA` is not a `QObject`.

Comment: Are you creating those pointers with `new`?  If so, I suggest you look into either `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`, or their Qt counterparts.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by clean

Comment: The best way is to use Qt algorithm `qDeleteAll()` defined in <QtAlgorithms>. It only applies `delete` on all of the vector's elements. You need to call `QVector::clear()` if that's necessary. If the vector-object is going to be destroyed, only `qDeleteAll()` is sufficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is in two lines of code:

```
while (list.count())
     delete list.takeLast();
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the documentation of [`QVector.clear()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#clear) - I think it answers your question quite well.

To preserve it, I copied it here:

**`void QVector::clear()`**

Removes all the elements from the vector.

***Note:** Until Qt 5.6, this also released the memory used by the vector. From Qt 5.7, the capacity is preserved. To shed all capacity, swap with a default-constructed vector:*

```
QVector<T> v ...;
QVector<T>().swap(v);
Q_ASSERT(v.capacity() == 0);
```

or call `squeeze()`.

Comment: in this case clear() release only the pointer list from the vector but it not free the memory since the pointer is manually reserved.

I try to do something like that

for (int index = 0; index < mList.count(); ++index )
{
    const ClassA* value = const_cast<ClassA*>(mList[index ]);
    delete value ;
}

Answer (score 2):

I would write :

```cpp
qDeleteAll(list);
list.clear();
```

---

**EDIT** (a few secondes after post) : My apologies to [Pie_Jesu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/530462/pie-jesu) who posted a (very) similar comment on the question, which I did not read when I was writting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

in this case **`clear()`** release only the pointer list from the vector but it not free the memory.

I try to do something like that

```
for (int index = 0; index < mList.count(); ++index )
{
    const ClassA* value = const_cast<ClassA*>(mList[index ]);
    delete value ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply suggest loop with a for each over it and delete every pointer. after that clear the vector

```
for(auto item : list){
    delete item;
}
list.clear();
```

Or simply use `QScopedPointer` elements of `classA` in your `list` and simply call `clear().`

Comment: that can work if the QVoctor contain a pointer of ClassA **QVector<ClassA*>** but in my case the QVector contain a const of **ClassA**.